# Do I have to typedef on every Header file?

Tags: c++, oop, typedef

Let's say I have an `std::vector` of `std::string`s.

```
// Foo.h
class Foo {
    std::vector< std::string > mVectorOfFiles;
}
```

Then I used `typedef` to make it a `StringVector` type.

```
// Foo.h
typedef std::vector< std::string > StringVector;

class Foo {
    StringVector mVectorOfFiles;
}
```

If I have another class which takes a `StringVector` object...

```
// Bar.h
class Bar {
    Bar( const StringVector & pVectorOfFiles ); // I assume this produces a compile error (?) since Bar has no idea what a StringVector is
}
```

... do I have to use `typedef` again in the header file for `Bar`?

```
// Bar.h
typedef std::string< std::vector > StringVector;
class Bar {
    Bar( StringVector pListOfFiles );
}
```

Is it possible to place the `typedef std::vector< std::string > StringVector` in a single file and have every other class know of the type `StringVector`?

Comment: You should consider to move the StringVector typedef to a common header file that's included by Foo.h and Bar.h.

Comment: Also make sore you change the signature to `Bar(const StringVector& listOfFiles);`. No need to create a copy there...

Comment: @RemusRusanu Well, you cannot know for sure that a copy is not needed: if `Bar` needs to store a copy of `pListOfFiles`, then it makes sense to take it by value and then move it into the data member. `class Bar { Bar(StringVector pListOfFiles) : mFiles(std::move(pListOfFiles)) {}, StringVector mFiles; };`

Comment: You could consider not typedef'ing that rather simple type *at all*... Personally, I have an aversion against typedefs that make me look up the *apparent* type to be sure about the *actual* type just so that the author saves a bit of typing (no pun intended). Function pointers, now, *they* are a different flavor of fish...

Comment: @DevSolar: agreed. There are three reasons for a typedef: "abstraction" (the alias is used in many places, and some day you might want to change them all at once; "compression" (you mention a long name multiple times and want to write less; and "complex compound types such as function types are unreadable". Compression potentially hinders the readability of the code in the way you say, particularly when the typedef is off in another file somewhere. Rule of thumb, if the user of the typedef name will need to know what the underlying type "is really", then you have not achieved abstraction.

Comment: @SteveJessop: ...and you need to know the underlying type as soon as you need to *do* anything with the object beyond passing it as parameter to another function (i.e., once you need to call a member function). `FILE *` is abstract, `StringVector` is not.

Comment: @DevSolar: yes. This is not "abstraction", it's "compression". Probably -- it's conceivable that the program has some intermediary functions that pass around `StringVector` references without actually using any functions of `vector`. In which case `Filenames` might be a better name for it (or given that the data member is called `mListOfFiles`, the type could be called `FileList`. But I'm a wary of calling something a "list" when it's a vector, that's misleading. `FilenameSequence`, perhaps).

Comment: ... and then you could document somewhere that the type `FilenameSequence` supports such-and-such operations, or perhaps that it's a ReversibleSequence with value_type `std::string`. Now you have an abstraction :-)

Comment: After reading some docs and books (as well as the comments here), I decided to not use `typedef` since the other devs I'm working with might overlook the `typedef` line and cause confusion.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

All files that `#include "Foo.h"` you get the `typedef`. So no, you don't *have* to replicate it in every file (as long as it includes `Foo.h`. You can place the `typedef` in a dedicated file if that suits your needs. In your case, this would make sense and would be an improvement, because `Bar.h` should not rely on the fact that `Foo.h` has the `typedef` and the necessary includes.

I would keep it simple and limit it to one type though, to be included in all files that use the type:

```
// StringVector.h
#ifndef STRINGVECTOR_H_
#define STRINGVECTOR_H_

#include <vector>
#include <string>

typedef std::vector< std::string > StringVector;

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course not, you do not have to typedef in all the header files, just do it in any header file that is included by the rest of source files.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class instead.

```
class Files {
};
```

Then you can use a forward declaration wherever it's needed;

```
class Files;
```

You will encapsulate behaviour appropriate to files.

Comment: Create a class for what? If want to replace the StringVector typedef with that class you will fail, since it's necessary to define the class before you define instances in Foo and Bar. So the forward is not applicable.

Comment: @harper For what? Encapsulation, reducing dependencies, semantics.

Comment: Hmm, I had the impression that Lance had a question about placing the typedef at the right position. Okay, encapsulation isn't bad. But I can't see how your proposal would help in this case when Lance wants to define classes with actual instances of the StringVector.

Comment: I'm addressing the larger question of why they have this problem in the first place. If I was going to use a `typedef` I'd associate it with another type, as the standard library containers do. However is this case, there doesn't seem to be a main class which would 'own' the `typedef`. If you spread the typdefs across headers you've got a lot more work if you want to change them. There is an illusion to being able to interchange data structures. They need to be appropriate to the algorithms performed on them. So I recommend encapsulation, and data hiding.